# Autocomplete window placed too high

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've got a jQuery UI autocomplete menu that is initially showing up too high and blocking the textbox. After a few more keystrokes, though, the box will move down to its proper position. Anyone ever run into this and know how to fix it, or is it a bug in jQuery-ui? The only other instance I can find of this is a bug entered [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6636) about two years ago that has been closed and marked for deletion. I get this in Chrome 26 and IE 10, but not Firefox 20.

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce in a small demo on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I tried, but I can't seem to reproduce it in there. See my answer for what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. It was a mismatch of jQuery/jQuery-UI versions causing a problem. Stupid MVC 4 template. In case anyone's interested, I was using jQuery 1.7.1 with jQuery-UI 1.10.1.